# findViewById reference unresolved

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I have a small app, where i have a fragment `AchievementFragment` and in there i have a few `imageButton`s. I want to make it so that when i click on one of them, a toast appears on the screen, but i have a problem with just the `imageButton` itself. I tried following a few online tutorials like this one: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/imagebutton-in-kotlin/, but when i try to use

```
val imgbtn = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageBtn)
```

i get unresolved findViewById reference error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use directly findViewById in fragments, you have to use it with root view, in your onCreateView you are returning the root view. Your other views are inside the root view. So if you want to access a view inside root you should use like this before returning the root view

```
 override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false)

    val imgbtn = root.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageBtn)
    
    return root
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val imgbtn = (activity as ActivityName).findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageBtn)
```

replace ActivityName with your activity name.

OR

Use View Binding instead of findViewById.
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

Comment: I tried it and it seems simpler and more readable that way. Thanks